# Aligning elements within a list element

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a list of `n` items.

I'm trying to align the `a` element having child `img`, next to  sibling `p` element.

I've tried setting both to `display:inline-block`, but I don't see any change. My code looks like this:

```
<li>
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <a href="#"><img src="example.img" alt=""></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate interdum lacus in hendrerit. Donec libero metus, maximus sit amet.</p>
 </li>
```

My goal is to create a sort of panel where the `a` element is to the left with the text next to it, and the `h3` centered in that same panel.

```html
<li>
  <h3>Header 3</h3>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="example.img" alt="">
  </a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate interdum lacus in hendrerit. Donec libero metus, maximus sit amet.</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand what your question goal. But, tell me if my answer was wrong :)

```css
li{
  list-style: none;
}
h3{
  text-align: center;
}
img{
  float: left;
}
p{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<li>
      <h3>Header 3</h3>
      <a href="#"><img src="example.img" alt=""></a>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate interdum lacus in hendrerit. Donec libero metus, maximus sit amet.</p>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display:inline-block` in `a` and `p` and set some `width`, use `text-align:center` in `h3`

```css
body,
h3,
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size:16px /* restore font-size inline-block fix*/
}
h3 {text-align: center}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0
  /*inline-block fix gap*/
}
li {
  background: red;
}
a,
li,
p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate interdum lacus in hendrerit. Donec libero metus, maximus sit amet.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="">
    </a>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vulputate interdum lacus in hendrerit. Donec libero metus, maximus sit amet.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```